# Facing error 'invalid SQL statement' while working with cursor variables in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors

Hi everyone hope you're doing well.
I'm new to PL/SQL and I'm trying to learn 'cursor variable' . I have made and example for myself and everything looks correct and I have no idea why it does not work.
my first procedure is

```
  create or replace procedure p_get_student_detail(s_id  number,
     s_cur out sys_refcursor) AS

    Begin

     open s_cur for
     select student_name, age from student where student_id = s_id;

   end;
```

and my second procedure in which I'm using the output of the first procedure is :

```
Create or replace procedure s_print_data(s_id number)

   as

    type ref_cur is ref cursor;
    s_refcur       ref_cur;
    s_student_name student.student_name%type;
    s_student_age  student.age%type;

 begin

    p_get_student_detail(s_id, s_refcur);

     loop
        fetch s_refcur into s_student_name, s_student_age;
        exit when s_refcur%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(s_student_name || s_student_age);
     end loop;
 end;
```

when I try to execute the procedure `exec s_print_data (1)` I see this error :

```
ORA - 00900:invalid SQL statement
```

I was wondering if you could help me with that.
Thanks

Comment: It's working fine on 11gr2 (Sql*plus and Oracle Sql Developer)

Comment: i'm using pl/sql developer and it shows the above mentioned error

Comment: You are missing ORA error number and line number.  Can you please updatr your question with thst information please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found where the problem is
the syntax for calling the procedure is incorrect
I have to call the procedure like this :

```
begin

   s_print_data(1);
  end;
```

and everything works fine

Comment: `exec` is an sqlplus command and not an sql command.  Some tools understand at least a subset of the sqlplus commands and some do not.